# Select fields in Like Query

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I'm trying to find documents using Regex in Mongodb but I also want to select fields to be returned : 
My code is

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
               ->getManager();
    $qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('ngNearBundle:Users')->select('lat,lng,title,photos,description');
    $titles=$qb->field('title')->equals(new \MongoRegex('/.*'.$key_words.'.*/i'))->getQuery()->execute()->toArray();
```

But the query returns an array with documents but all fields are NULL (All fields are returned and not only the selected ones! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select() call syntax is as follows :

```
$qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('ngNearBundle:Users')
    ->select('lat','lng','title','photos','description');
```

Fields have to be distinct arguments at the php method level.